# How do I Extract ADDRESS info from a fakeaddressgenerator using selenium python

Tags: selenium

I am new to python selenium i want to extract Address info from this website and print

```
Street
City
State/Province abbr
State/Province full
Zip Code/Postal code
Mobile Number
```

**Example output:**

```
4936 Sheila Lane
Goshute
NV
Nevada
84083
702-499-6666
```

```html
https://www.fakeaddressgenerator.com/World_Address/get_us_address1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically we are using `dict.` to store each and every information. also list to store all the details.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://www.fakeaddressgenerator.com/World_Address/get_us_address1")

contact_info = []
for details in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//b[text()='ADDRESS']/ancestor::tr/following-sibling::tr/descendant::b"):
    contact_info.append(details.text)

data = {
         'Street': contact_info[0],
         'City' : contact_info[1],
         'State/Province abbr': contact_info[2],
         'State/Province full': contact_info[3],
         'Zip Code/Postal code': contact_info[4],
         'Phone Number': contact_info[5],
        'Mobile Number' : contact_info[6]
        }

print(data.get('Zip Code/Postal code'))
```

Comment: Its working well But i want to store them in relevant variables like Street
City
State/Province abbr
State/Province full
Zip Code/Postal code
Mobile Number

Comment: Can You help me with that?

Comment: and then print each thing according to my needs like print zip only or city only

Comment: see above I have updated to have everything in a list `contact_info ` the output will look something like this `['3870 Allison Avenue', 'Chesapeake', 'VA', 'Virginia', '23323', '757-558-0698', '757-573-4828', '07mkdynxkxa3@temporary-mail.net']`

Comment: @MuazmaTech : Check out the new code, I am using `dict` data structure now, and storing the data like above.

Comment: Thanks Sir, I actually did with your old modification !!! Thanks a lot Sir!!!

Comment: yeah no issue, I will look into this ticket  now which you have created recently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69001473/how-do-i-extract-data-from-yelp-using-selenium-python

Comment: okay that looks like a little big task, I will take around 1-2 hours, I will update there.

Comment: I have the code, which is linke 80-90% completed, but that web app is too dynamic