# How do i extract data from yelp using selenium python

Tags: selenium

I am new to python!! I want to Extract data from yelp

```
https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=nails+salons&find_loc=San+Francisco%2C+CA&ns=1
```

and then from clicking on name on 1st page ...i.e

```
https://www.yelp.com/biz/joy-joy-nail-and-spa-san-francisco?osq=nails+salons
```

it should extract

```
Name
Address 
Website
Contact No
Rating (How many) in numbers
```

and then it should continue doing so for full page
Example output

```
Joy Joy Nail & Spa 
4023 24th St San Francisco, CA 94114
joyjoynailspa.com
(415) 655-3216
6 Reviews




Sunset Nails
1810 Irving St 
San Francisco, CA 94122
(415) 566-9888
1185 reviews
```

if any of the element not present like website it should skip that info and continue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, basically you have to go to page, then using `find_elements` have to see how many items are present to scrape, then select the first one and scrape the desire elements and go back to the previous page and do the same for other products.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=nails+salons&find_loc=San+Francisco%2C+CA&ns=1")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
lnght = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'businessName')]/descendant::a"))
j = 0
for item in range(lnght):
    elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'arrange-unit') and contains(@class,'arrange-unit-fill')]//ancestor::div[contains(@class,'container') and contains(@class,'hover')]")
    time.sleep(1)
    #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elements[j])
    eles = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//h4/descendant::a")
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(eles[j]).click().perform()
    #elements[j].click()
    time.sleep(2)
    print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'headingLight')]//h1"))).text)
    print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[text()='Business website']/following-sibling::p/a"))).text)
    print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[text()='Phone number']/following-sibling::p"))).text)
    print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Get Directions']/../following-sibling::p"))).text)
    print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'reviews')]"))).text)
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
    time.sleep(2)
    j = j + 1
```

**Update 1 :**

Whichever line is causing the issue, try to wrap them like this :

```
try:
    print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[text()='Business website']/following-sibling::p/a"))).text)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Thank You Sir sorry actually when element like website is not present it is not able to skip it !! It is actually trying and stuck there is there anyway to bypass it?? and also if i want it to go to multiple pages if user ask can it have a input that ask how many pages?

Comment: Yes, at my end this website loads very slow, even I have good internet speed. What about you ? Does it take more time to load ?

Comment: Yes it is working a little slow !!! But i am using RDP for Better Performance!!!

Comment: Basically the script should scrape all of them, but due to poor web application performance, I am not able to test it fully

Comment: Yes it is Scraping all Good!!! But Like in the 3rd result the website name is not present but actually it is try for finding that result !! is there any way like Through exception or some like try and catch to bypass it and store the rest info?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ALI\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\yelpscrap.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[text()='Business website']/following-sibling::p/a"))).text)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: yes, it is there. I can update the it with try-catch tomorrow, it's really late in the night, I gotta go and have some sleep before I pass out :D LOL

Comment: Also, increase time in implicit wait and explicit waits above. `driver.implicitly_wait(500)` and `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)`

Comment: @MuazmaTech : also see the updated 1 code above for try-except